# How to reuse old LPT HASP key?

Tags: hardware, lpt, hasp

I've got a bunch of old LPT HASP keys. [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jotAf.jpg)

Is there a way to interrogate these?
Can I use these HASP Keys as a source of random values or something like that?

Maybe there is a better way to give those things a second life?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can explain only about HASP keys.

If you got these keys along with the purchase of any software then you can't do anything with them.
If you are a software developer and got these keys for protection own software then you should have a USB Master key or two private passwords. Having them you can store data inside these keys or encrypt/decrypt any data. For this, you need to use HASP API: https://www3.safenet-inc.com/support/hasp/hasp4/Win32api.aspx

Comment: W3Schools often contains out of date and incorrect information.
For JavaScript, please reference the 
[Mozilla Developer Network (or MDN)](https://developer.mozilla.org/) 
- it is far more likely to remain accurate and updated over time.

Comment: @Mikhail this pretty much answers my question, thank you.